# Flight offers pricing giving unexpected results after adding bags

Tags: amadeus

I tried to follow this guide https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/add-baggage-amadeus-flight-booking-api on retrieving flight offer price.

After first request to the pricing endpoint I get:

```
"included": {                                                                                                                                                    
  "bags": {                                                                                                                                                      
    "1": {                                                                                                                                                       
      "quantity": 1,                                                                                                                                             
      "name": "CHECKED_BAG",                                                                                                                                     
      "price": {                                                                                                                                                 
        "amount": "1637",                                                                                                                                        
        "currencyCode": "NOK"                                                                                                                                    
      },                                                                                                                                                         
      "bookableByItinerary": true,                                                                                                                               
      "segmentIds": [                                                                                                                                            
        "3",                                                                                                                                                     
        "21"                                                                                                                                                     
      ],                                                                                                                                                         
      "travelerIds": [                                                                                                                                           
        "0",                                                                                                                                                     
        "1"                                                                                                                                                      
      ]                                                                                                                                                          
    },                                                                                                                                                           
    "2": {                                                                                                                                                       
      "quantity": 1,                                                                                                                                             
      "name": "CHECKED_BAG",                                                                                                                                     
      "price": {                                                                                                                                                 
        "amount": "655",                                                                                                                                         
        "currencyCode": "NOK"                                                                                                                                    
      },                                                                                                                                                         
      "bookableByItinerary": true,                                                                                                                               
      "segmentIds": [                                             
        "3",
        "21"
      ],
      "travelerIds": [                                            
        "0",
        "1"
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

To be honest I'm not sure how to interpret that. What do the `"1"` and `"2"` keys represent here? Are those for the first and the second flight offer that I sent in the request?

Anyway, after getting this response I'm assigning `1` to `travelerPricings.fareDetailsBySegment.additionalServices.chargeableCheckedBags.quantity` to every segment (ids "3" and "21") in every flight offer (2 of them).

I was expecting to get different prices in a response for a second request, but I got the same thing and additional services are never mentioned in the second response to flight offers pricing.

Am I doing something wrong?

I also tried to add bags for just one segment and the same thing happened.

I'm looking for a JFK<->MAD flight (2020-10-20 -> 2020-10-30).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “1” and “2” are the id’s of the bag offers. In this case the API returns the offer 1 with 1 bag for 1637 NOK and the offer 2 with 1 bag for 655 NOK. By the price difference it means that one bag is bigger than the other even though the airline hasn’t provided explicitly this information. The segmentId in each bag offer guarantees which bag offer can be applied to which segment. Now, in this case both bag offers have the same quantity = 1. In order to choose which bag offer you want to add in the flight (as both offers have the same quantity), you can manually update the price of the flight offer with the one of the bag you’ve selected, so the system will know which bag to add.

When the price returned after adding the bags to the flight offers is the same, it means the bag was not possible to be added. This can be linked to several things such as: this bag is not available to a specific segment, due to the test environment data and it's limitations the amount of bags is not available while confirming in the flight offers price, or specific airlines allow only one bag for each person, or even the specific flight reached the limit of bag capacity as there is not unlimited amount of space.

Comment: _By the price difference it means that one bag is bigger than the other even though the airline hasn’t provided explicitly this information_ - is this also possible to happen in production environment? Also, what is the `qauantity` exactly? If quantity is equal 1, does it mean that every traveler can have one of these, or is it max one for all travelers? And what if there are many different bags with different quantity - how do I add a specific one?

Comment: Oh and do I update the price in the `travelerPricings`?

Comment: Would you be so kind to answer these questions? Unfortunately the documentation website is going down almost every time I visit it, so I can't even send a question through contact form.

Comment: Both test and production environments have the same behaviour. The “quantity” returned is the max quantity of bag that can be booked by each impacted traveler Ids and segment ids. Each bag offer is coupled to specific segment id and traveler id. We already discussed privately for the specific use case but some insights here might be useful for other users who read the post.

Comment: One more question arised: What about `travelerPricings`? When I'm asking amadeus for prices, then only the `price.grandTotal` field is updated, but the `total` prices for a specific traveler remains the same. Is this supposed to be like that?